# Hot to remove/replace tags but keep the content?

Tags: notepad++

Say I have a huge amount of files where I can see structures similar to the following:
`<li><p>text.</p><p>some other text.</p></li>`
This is not what I want. I want the following:
`<li>text.<p>some other text.</p></li>`
I know how to find such instances (`<li><p>.*</p> <p>.*</p></li>`) however I have no idea how to replace them but to keep the content unchanged.
Is it even possible?

Comment: To be clear, you want to remove the first `<p>` and `</p>` in a `<li>...</li>`, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case

```
Find what:     <li><p>(.*?)</p><p>(.*?)</p></li>
Replace with:  <li>\1<p>\2</p></li>

Match Case: checked
Regular expression: checked
.matches newline: check
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<li>)<p>(.+?)</p>`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(<li>)          # group 1, open <li> tag
<p>             # open <p> tag
(.+?)           # group 2, 1 or more any character, not greedy
</p>            # close </p> tag
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1 (<li>)
$2      # ccontent of group 2 (text.)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @AnastasijaDatsun: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)